# Python 3 - Help me modify this regex please

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working through Python coding book and the task is:

Input: "42 1,234 6,368,745 12,34,567 1234"
Make regex that matches 42 1,234 6,368,745 but does NOT matches 12,34,567 1234
So basically it should only match normal numbers with comma \d{1,3} and then only \d{3} between commas. I created:

`r'^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$'`

that works when I split the string, loop over every number and use re.search.
But when I want to go through entire string and use re.findall, I needed to recreate the regex entirely to

`r'(((\s|^)\d{1,3}(?!\d|,)|(\s|^)\d{1,3},(\d{3},|\d{3}(?!,))+))'`

Because it needs to deal with spaces as well. But is there better and shorter regex for findall in this case? Because it looks awful...
Sorry for my english :/ ask me anything if needed.

Code for findall:

```
text ="42 1,234 6,368,745 12,34,567 1234"
regex = re.compile(r'(((\s|^)\d{1,3}(?!\d|,)|(\s|^)\d{1,3},(\d{3},|\d{3}(?!,))+))')
found = ""
finden = regex.findall(text)
print(finden)
```

Code for search:

```
text ="42 1,234 6,368,745 12,34,567 1234"
text = text.split(" ")
regex = re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$')
found = ""
for value in text:
    print(value)
    find = regex.search(str(value))
    if find is None:
        continue
    found = found + find.group() + "; "
print(found)
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/5pI3Bj/1